# jquery-ui-tabs at bottom with no header , css issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

**Statement:**

using jquery ui tabs , I am trying to combine 2 features taken from **[this website](http://keith-wood.name/uiTabs.html)**.
Tabs at bottom , tabs with no header.
 1. If I use class pos-bottom only.it works.
 2. If I use class no-header only.it works.

**Problem:**
When I use both classes (pos-bottom,no-header), CSS breaks. Can any one suggest why ?You can Find my JSFIDDLE try below.

I want tabs at bottom with no header. Right now default tabs at top work correct with no header. But when i force tabs at bottom, I get weird borders.

**JSFIDDLE Try:** http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/9PUJ2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test" class="pos-bottom no-header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">tab1</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">tab2</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">tab3</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#test').tabs();
```

**CSS:**

```
/** tabs with no header **/
.no-header {
    padding: 0px;
    background: none;
    border-width: 0px;
}
.no-header .ui-tabs-nav {
    padding-left: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.no-header .ui-tabs-panel {  
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}



/**  pos-bottom **/
.pos-bottom { 
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 3em; 
} 
.pos-bottom .ui-tabs-nav { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0.25em; 
    right: 0.25em; 
    bottom: 0.25em; 
    padding: 0em 0.2em 0.2em; 
} 
.pos-bottom .ui-tabs-nav li { 
    border-top: none; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; 

} 
.pos-bottom .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected, 
.pos-bottom .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active { 
    margin-top: -1px; padding-top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain "When I use both classes (pos-bottom,no-header), CSS breaks"...Means what exactly happens?

Comment: It means you want to hide header also and show header button of tabs in bottom? I think statment has contradiction?

Comment: Assuming this is because you have 2 classes `pos-bottom` and `no-header` for the same parent `div` element. So, according to your css `no-header` will be applied firstly and right after that `pos-bottom` will override it. That's why you can't apply 2 styles. Try to combine you css or so.

Comment: Yes, i want tabs at bottom with no header.And I am not good with css :).Edited question for clarity.

Comment: @django can you lil bit make me clear what you exactly want

Comment: is this what you want [link](http://jsfiddle.net/arun_/9PUJ2/1/)

Comment: Thank you @Arun Maddheshia.